# Create setter dynamically?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there way to add setter to object dynamically like this?

```js
output = document.querySelector(".output")
log = (out)=>{
  output.innerHTML = out
}

class A {
  constructor(some){
    this._some = some
  }    
}

myObj = new A(1)
// myObj = Add setter there...
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

I just need this to write classes which instaces can dynamically create setters to their properties.

Comment: You can add a setter for a property, but you can't add a setter for a variable (AFAIK). What does `myObj = Add setter there...` mean? Are you looking for decorators?

Comment: "can dynamically create setters to their properties" you need to provide an example of this behaviour. Class instances are objects and yes you can define new properties having setters on them. What is the problem?

Comment: No, I don't. I need for example if I add property "a" to my object be able to add "setA" setter to this object out of it's class logic.

Comment: That's what decorators are used for.

Comment: I familiar with syntax to add setters inside a class or objects code, but I can't assing them to objects from outside.

I need to solution like this:
class A{}
myobj = new A()
myobj.someprop = "somevalue"
but instead of "somevalue" i need to put setter and I haven't idea to how to do this.

Comment: Yes, you do `Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'a', { set(value) { console.log(value) }})`

Comment: You don't "add" a setter. You create a class and pass the class to a decorator. The decorator creates a new class with setters for all properties. That's what TypeScript decorators do in the background. You can do the same with objects instead of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
class A {
  constructor(some){
    this[some] = some // This needs to be a string, otherwise it doesn't work
  }    
}
```

If you need to do more complex stuff you can do something like:

```
const exampleInput = {
  prop1: 123,
  prop2: "someString"
}

class A {
  // Make some an object like the one above
  constructor(some){
    for (prop in some) {
       this[prop] = some[prop]
    }
  }    
}
```

[Explanation on for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
class A {
  constructor(some){
    this._some = some
  }    
}

let myObj = new A(1)

console.log(myObj._some) // 1

Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'setSome', {
  set: function(x) { this._some = x ; }
});

myObj.setSome = 77;
console.log(myObj._some) // 77
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I'm already found it. I still don't know why people decreases my reputation :(